# Angular 4 How to dynamically load the base-href value from an external file

Tags: angular

I have a stand alone angular app. we have multiple environments and hence need to change the base-href value as the environments change. The window.location will not work because the folder structure changes for each environment. so looking for a solution where it can be loaded from an external file.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about runtime or build time?

Comment: During Runtime. The values should be picked up from an external file.